# beamer: Centering title page contents

Tags: beamer, horizontal-alignment, titles, beamer-metropolis

For this theme, how can I center the title and/or the remaining elements on the title page?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{metropolis}

\title{long long long long long long long long long long long long long long title}
\author{me}
\institute{institute}
\date{1 September 2017}

\begin{document}
    \maketitle
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{metropolis}

\title{long long long long long long long long long long long long long long title}
\author{me}
\institute{institute}
\date{1 September 2017}

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{title page}{
  \begin{minipage}[b][\paperheight]{\textwidth}
    \centering  % <-- Center here
    \ifx\inserttitlegraphic\@empty\else\usebeamertemplate*{title graphic}\fi
    \vfill%
    \ifx\inserttitle\@empty\else\usebeamertemplate*{title}\fi
    \ifx\insertsubtitle\@empty\else\usebeamertemplate*{subtitle}\fi
    \usebeamertemplate*{title separator}
    \ifx\beamer@shortauthor\@empty\else\usebeamertemplate*{author}\fi
    \ifx\insertdate\@empty\else\usebeamertemplate*{date}\fi
    \ifx\insertinstitute\@empty\else\usebeamertemplate*{institute}\fi
    \vfill
    \vspace*{1mm}
  \end{minipage}
}

\setbeamertemplate{title}{
%  \raggedright%  % <-- Comment here
  \linespread{1.0}%
  \inserttitle%
  \par%
  \vspace*{0.5em}
}
\setbeamertemplate{subtitle}{
%  \raggedright%  % <-- Comment here
  \insertsubtitle%
  \par%
  \vspace*{0.5em}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \titlepage
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. May I know if there is a difference between `\begin{frame}
    \centering
    \titlepage
\end{frame}` and just `\maketitle`?

Comment: @DiaaAbidou The outcome is the same, if you use `\maketitle` outside a frame, it will insert `\frame{\titlepage}`.  With `\begin{frame}
    \titlepage
\end{frame}` you have more freedom to add things to the frame or do `\begin{frame}[plain]`. In the above code it has no deeper meaning, just a relict of some testing I did to find a suitable spot to add `\centering` :)