# Change position of title and text in a beamer titlepage

Tags: beamer, graphics, align, positioning, frame-title

Currently I am working in a presentation and this is the code that generates my titlepage:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}

\usetheme[progressbar=frametitle]{metropolis}
\usepackage{appendixnumberbeamer}

% ===================
% Metropolis BrownU Theme\\
% https://github.com/vskbellala/metropolis-brown
\usepackage{metropolisbrown}
% ===================

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[scale=2]{ccicons}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{dateplot}

\usepackage{xspace}
\newcommand{\themename}{\textbf{\textsc{metropolis}}\xspace}

\title{Quaterniões}
\subtitle{Processamento de imagens e diversos}
\author{\href{https://www.ua.pt/pt/p/80632481}{Rodrigo Domingues}}
\institute{}
\date{\vspace{.25cm} \scriptsize{Orientadores: \hspace*{.2cm} 
          \begin{itemize}
            \item[]{Prof. Dr. Milton Ferreira}
            \item[]{Prof. Dr. Nelson Vieira}
          \end{itemize}}
          \vspace{.25cm}
          \small{Departamento de Matemática, Universidade de Aveiro\begin{center} 2022 \end{center}}}           
\titlegraphic{\hfill\href{https://www.ua.pt/pt/dmat/}{\includegraphics[height=1cm]{dmat_ua_nobg.png}}}  

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

The output I get from this code is: [image]

My desired output would be to have more vertical distance from the top of the page to the text, i.e., moving my text closer to the end of the page, leaving more space between the image and the main title of the beamer. Something like this:

[image]

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: offtopic: Does *Quaterniões* mean *Quaternions*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Redefining the titlepage (see for example [Redefine metropolis title page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/388878/161015)) instead of using `\date` to include the new fields.

There are two minipages. The upper one includes the title, the subtitle and the logo. The lower the remaining fields.

There are several `\vspaces*` between the different elements in the definition that allow the layout to be easily changed.

[image: a]

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}

\usetheme[progressbar=frametitle]{metropolis}
\usepackage{appendixnumberbeamer}

% ===================
% Metropolis BrownU Theme\\
% https://github.com/vskbellala/metropolis-brown
\usepackage{metropolisbrown}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[scale=2]{ccicons}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{dateplot}

\usepackage{xspace}
\newcommand{\themename}{\textbf{\textsc{metropolis}}\xspace}

\setbeamertemplate{title page}{% added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
        \ifx\inserttitlegraphic\@empty\else\usebeamertemplate*{title graphic}\fi
        \vspace*{5em}
        \ifx\inserttitle\@empty\else\usebeamertemplate*{title}\fi
        \ifx\insertsubtitle\@empty\else\usebeamertemplate*{subtitle}\fi
        \usebeamertemplate*{title separator}
    \end{minipage}
    \vfill  
    \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
        \vspace*{0.6em}% 
        \ifx\beamer@shortauthor\@empty\else\usebeamertemplate*{author}\fi
        \vspace*{0.25em}
        {\scriptsize Orientadores: \par
        \vspace*{0.25em}
        \hspace{3.0em}Prof. Dr. Milton Ferreira \par
        \vspace*{0.25em}
        \hspace{3.0em}Prof. Dr. Nelson Vieira} \par
        \vspace*{0.25em}
        \ifx\insertinstitute\@empty\else\usebeamertemplate*{institute}\fi
        \centering  \vspace*{1em} \ifx\insertdate\@empty\else\usebeamertemplate*{date}\fi
    \end{minipage}
}

\title{Quaterniões}
\subtitle{Processamento de imagens e diversos}
\author{\href{https://www.ua.pt/pt/p/80632481}{Rodrigo Domingues }}

\institute{Departamento de Matemática, Universidade de Aveiro}

\date{2022}
    
\titlegraphic{\hfill\href{https://www.ua.pt/pt/dmat/}{\includegraphics[height=1cm]{logo.jpg}}}  

\begin{document}
    
    \maketitle
    
\end{documen
```